# Search an object with camera

Tags: android, ios, augmented-reality

There are some virtual objects crawling (moving slowly & randomly) in a virtual plane, say 3m x 3m (2-dimensional, in parallel with the floor).

I would like to find the object out using Augmented Reality technology, by seeking around using camera view in **Android** and **iOS**. Is it possible? If yes, is there any toolkit/framework that does the work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure if this is what you're looking for, but if you try the example [here](http://www.junaio.com/fileadmin/upload/documents/Promo_Booklet/DOC-junaio_promo_book-EN-DIGI.pdf) called Space ShootAR( next to last page), there are little storm troopers running around randomly that you are supposed to shoot.

It's built in Junaio and works for both Android and iOS.

Do you intend to user a marker on the floor or do you want to use the floor itself as a marker? Depending on the exact situation you plan to create, there are different sdks.

If this example doesn't fit what you're looking for, perhaps you could provide a bit more information?
Hope this helps a bit though.

Comment: The first part of your answer is good, and it's fine to have answers that you're not 100% positive of (the asker and the readers will evaluate), but you should put your request for more information in a separate comment on the question.  (well, at least after you gain enough rep to add comments)

Comment: @Amanda thanks for the answer. There are quite a lot of apps / companies doing the AR technology, but I'm trying to find a framework  / toolkit doing so. Any suggestion?

Comment: @shivanraptor Junaio is a framework in addition to being an augmented reality browser/app that lets you launch what you build. Dev info [here](http://www.junaio.com/develop/)  The only other one one I'm really familiar with is [metaio sdk](http://www.metaio.com/products/sdk/), but this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921895/augmented-reality) listed a bunch of other ones.